# Apache htaccess multiple rewritecond

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, web, webserver

I'm having issues in writing rewritecond in the htaccess file on my web server. If someone could help me out, it would be very helpful to me.

What I want to accomplish is these 2 things:
1. Redirect all requests to http: // domain.com to http: // www.domain.com
2. Redirect/ remove the index.html part from the URL if it exists.

My current htaccess settings are:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{http_host} ^example.com [nc]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http ://www. example. com/$1 [R=301,NC]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /.*index\.html\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.html$ [b]http :// www. example. com[/b]/$1 [R=301,L]
```

What happens is that when the URL contains index.html, it basically gives a 404 page. Not sure where the redirects are looping. Cam someone chime in to shed some light on the issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First rule tested out, second untested but *should* work. :)

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

# redirect domain.com to www.domain.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z0-9\-]+)\.([a-z0-9\-]+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) http://www.%1.%2/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^/?index\.html(\?.*)? /$1 [R=301]
```

Comment: Perfect! I changed a bit to remove all index.html at any level, but this works great now:
<br/>Options +FollowSymlinks
<br/>RewriteEngine on

<br/>RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z0-9\-]+)\.([a-z0-9\-]+)$ [NC]

<br/>RewriteRule ^/?(.*) http://www.%1.%2/$1 [R=301,L]

<br/>RewriteRule ^(.*)/?index\.html(\?.*)? /$1 [R=301]